# Probability Theory, Symmetric Difference

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show this property of the symmetric difference between two sets defined for two sets in a universe $A$ and $B$ by
$$
A\Delta B=(A\cap B^{c})\cup(B\cap A^{c})
$$
I need to show that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C)\leq \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)
$$
for sets $A, B,$ and $C$ in the universe.

I showed in the first part of the problem that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-2\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)
$$
My idea was to note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C)\leq\mathbb{P}(A\cap C^{c})+\mathbb{P}(C\cap A^{c})
$$
by probability laws and then leverage the fact that for any set I can write it as a union with another set. That is
$$
\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)+\mathbb{P}(B^{c}\cap A)
$$
and likewise for $C$ to substitute in for $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ terms. However, I end up running in circles. My TA did say I was on the right track, though. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Visually, using Venn diagrams, it is true. From this perspective we can define a strategy. The point for this strategy is to see that what you lose from some difference you get back again by the other difference, i.e. each symmetric difference compensate the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what you proved, we can write the inequality that we want to show as 
$$
P(A) + P(C) - 2 P(A \cap C) \leq P(A) + P(B) - 2 P(A \cap B) + P(B) + P(C) - 2 P(B \cap C).
$$
Subtracting redundant terms, we see that this inequality is equivalent to 
$$
- 2 P(A \cap C) \leq 2 P(B) - 2 P(A \cap B) - 2 P (B \cap C).
$$
Then, dividing by 2, 
$$
-P(A \cap C) \leq P(B) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C).
$$
So, it suffices to show 
$$
P(B) + P(A \cap C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) \geq 0.
$$
Now, using your trick on $P(B)$, we can write this inequality as 
$$
P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap C) - P (A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) \geq 0 
$$
and then cancelling, 
$$
P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) \geq 0.
$$
This inequality is true because 
$$
B \cap C = \{A^c \cap [B \cap C] \} \cup \{A \cap [B \cap C]\} \subseteq \{A^c \cap B\} \cup \{A \cap C\}.
$$
Indeed, because of the above, we have by the monotonicity of probability, 
$$
P(B \cap C) \leq P(\{A^c \cap B\} \cup \{A \cap C\}) \leq P(A^c \cap B) + P(A \cap C).
$$

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use the following formula:
$$
(A\bigtriangleup C) \subset (A\bigtriangleup B) \cup (B\bigtriangleup C)
$$
The proof is as follow:
\begin{align}
A\bigtriangleup C &=(A\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap A^c)
\\
&=((A\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap A^c))\cap (B\cup B^c)
\\
&=(A\cap C^c\cap B)\cup(C\cap A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap C^c\cap B^c)\cup(C\cap A^c\cap B^c)
\\
&\subset (C^c\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)\cup(C\cap B^c)
\\
&=((A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B))\cup((C^c\cap B)\cup(C\cap B^c))
\\
&=(A\bigtriangleup B) \cup (B\bigtriangleup C)
\end{align}

**Edit:**  By section 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.02224), the symmetric difference of two sets can be interpreted as the modular difference of two numbers, i.e.
$$
A\bigtriangleup B=|A-B|
$$
As a result, the above relation can be better understood and remembered if it is written as follows:
$$
|A-C|\subset|A-B|\cup|B-C|
$$
which is analogous to the triangular inequality of three numbers, i.e.
$$
|a-b|\leqslant|a-b|+|b-c|
$$

Answer (score 6):

If $\chi_U$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $U$, then we have $\chi_{A\Delta B} = |\chi_A - \chi_B|$. Hence we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C) &= \int |\chi_A - \chi_C| d\mu \\
&= \int |(\chi_A - \chi_B) + (\chi_B - \chi_C)| d\mu \\ 
&\leq \int (|\chi_A - \chi_B| + |\chi_B - \chi_C|) d\mu \\
&= \int (|\chi_A - \chi_B|d\mu + \int |\chi_B - \chi_C|) d\mu\\
&= \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B) +  \mathbb{P}(B\Delta C) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice and concise +1