# Show that for every sets $A, B, C$, $\mathbb P(A\Delta C)\leq \mathbb P(A\Delta B)+\mathbb P(B\Delta C).$

Tags: probability

I'm stuck in the proof of the following question. I solved (i) by drawing picture. I have no idea for (ii)

> 5. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two sets, we define the symmetric difference $A_1\Delta A_2$ by
>      $$A_1\Delta A_2 = (A_1\cap A_2^c)\cup(A_2\cap A_1^c).$$
>      (This is simply the set of all points that either in $A$ or $B$ but not both.) Show that
>      (i) $\mathbb P(A_1\Delta A_2) = \mathbb P(A_1)+\mathbb P(A_2)-2\mathbb P(A_1\cap A_2)$ and
>      (ii) for every sets $A, B, C$,
>      $$\mathbb P(A\Delta C)\leq \mathbb P(A\Delta B)+\mathbb P(B\Delta C).$$

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOQvx.jpg)

I feel like I have a hard time solving this kind of proof question. Does anyone have some good tips and suggestion?

Thank you so much ahead!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944509/probability-theory-symmetric-difference/1944557#1944557

Comment: @Muralidharan: Not a duplicate: that question covers only part (ii) of this one.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The proposer got stuck only in (ii) and hence added that comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if we can do this but can we restate problem as problem with cardinalities instead of propabilities? Or better yet as a problem in set theory? By multiplying by $|U|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the part (ii) is a duplicate of [Probability Theory, Symmetric Difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944509/probability-theory-symmetric-difference/1944557#1944557), I will answer only the part (i).

By the principle of inclusion-exclusion we have $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1)+\mathbb{P}(A_2)-\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$. Therefore to show that $\mathbb{P}(A_1\Delta A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1)+\mathbb{P}(A_2)-2\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{P}(A_1\Delta A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)-\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$.

The sets $A_1\Delta A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2$ are disjoint and $A_1\cup A_2=\left(A\Delta A_2\right)\cup\left(A_1\cap A_2\right)$. Thus by an axiom of probability we have $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1\Delta A_2)+\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$. In other words, we have $\mathbb{P}(A_1\Delta A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)-\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$, and we are done.